# What is the name of this Sicilian Variation?

Tags: opening, sicilian-defense, najdorf

What is the name of this variation:

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 Nf6 5.Nc3 a6 6.Bg5 Nbd7
```

Comment: `1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 Nf6 5.Nc3 a6` is the Najdorf variation. I don't know if `6.Bg5 Nbd7` has a name of its own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an old main line of Sicilian Najdorf, and according to Wikipedia, it's the [De Verbeterde List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sicilian_Defence,_Najdorf_Variation#Verbeterde_List:_6...Nbd7), or Improved Strategem, due to recent efforts by Dutch players to revive it.

Comment: In a few years, it may well become known as "the Vachier-Lagrave-variation", due to MVL use of this line at the highest level and his contribution to its theory.

Comment: @OlivierPucher I believe 6 ... e6 is more popular nowadays among the best players including MVL.

Comment: @user1583209 They probably transpose almost all the time